# Range 1 to 9223372036854775807 with regular expression

Tags: regex

I am trying to get this working and its nearly there but not quite!

I need to be able to allow a range from `1` to `9223372036854775807`.

I have the following regex:

```
^([1-9][0-9]{0,18}|9223372036854775807)$
```

That allows me to enter values in the range I want, but it also allows it to go to `9999999999999999999` Is it easy to block it to only to go to `9223372036854775807`?

Comment: What language are you trying to do this with?  That looks roughly like the max value of a 64 bit integer... perhaps you could just read the value into an arbitrary precision int and compare it?

Comment: No, don't use regex to check range of numbers (unless you want to make person who will maintain your code your worst enemy who will probably know where you live). Instead parse it to numeric value and use `<` and `>` operators.

Comment: not a job for regex. you should know what's regex for first before choosing it as a tool.

Comment: Why are you using a regex for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Don't use a regex. It's inefficient, and way worse than any integer parsing logic anyone can ever write.

For the sake of demonstration, here you go:

```regex
^(?:[1-9][0-9]{0,17}|[1-8][0-9]{18}|9(?:[01][0-9]{17}|2(?:[01][0-9]{16}|2(?:[0-2][0-9]{15}|3(?:[0-2][0-9]{14}|3(?:[0-6][0-9]{13}|7(?:[01][0-9]{12}|20(?:[0-2][0-9]{10}|3(?:[0-5][0-9]{9}|6(?:[0-7][0-9]{8}|8(?:[0-4][0-9]{7}|5(?:[0-3][0-9]{6}|4(?:[0-6][0-9]{5}|7(?:[0-6][0-9]{4}|7(?:[0-4][0-9]{3}|5(?:[0-7][0-9]{2}|80[0-7]))))))))))))))))$
```

Instead, parse it into an integer using the standard libraries of the language you are working in, and use value checks instead (`>` operators, et cetera).

Comment: Now, how about leading zeroes? ;) (and no, never mind, going to be a horrible expression if you handle that)

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Nope, not allowed :) The regex only accepts values which starts with a digit and follow a set that asserts being within the range, of which the leading digit is never zero to be validated.

Comment: Actually, could that be as simple as adding this: `^0*(?:...` ?

Comment: Yeah, if you look at OP's example, leading zeros are not allowed though.

Comment: Thanks guys, I actually found a "solution"! We are using a rules file so this has to be regex to keep it as is with the other 100+ rules. What I found is working is below.

Comment: \b([1-9][0-9]{0,17}|[1-8][0-9]{18}|9([01][0-9]{17}|2([01][0-9]{16}|2([0-2][0-9]{15}|3([0-2][0-9]{14}|3([0-6][0-9]{13}|7([01][0-9]{12}|20([0-2][0-9]{10}|3([0-5][0-9]{9}|6([0-7][0-9]{8}|8([0-4][0-9]{7}|5([0-3][0-9]{6}|4([0-6][0-9]{5}|7([0-6][0-9]{4}|7([0-4][0-9]{3}|5([0-7][0-9]{2}|80[0-7]))))))))))))))))\b

Comment: @aidangill What difference is that from my regex in the post?

Comment: Unihedron - Sorry I didn't spot your edited posts, the original one didn't work so I had posted what I found before you edited your to add what you did.

Comment: @aidangill Yes, the anchors were added after Lasse pointed it out - You can view the revisions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26759827/revisions), which revealed the presence of anchors at the timestamp of your message. Sorry for the confusion caused!

Comment: Not at all, great to get a solution! :D

Answer (score 0):

bc is pretty quick for a large number check like this:

`while read -p "Enter value: " a; do [[ $(echo "9223372036854775807 - $a" | bc) -gt 0 ]] && echo good || echo bad; done`